# How to bundle JAR with only ONE dependency

Tags: java, maven

I want to publish my library on Maven Central. Although one of my [dependencies](https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection/tree/master/lib) is a JAR file that is not on Maven Central. How do I ensure that dependency JAR is included in my library so when I publish it on Maven Central, whoever downloads my library doesn't need to go find the JAR and include that too.

I'm trying to avoid bundling of my dependencies.

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid bundling of my dependencies" then you can't

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid bundling of my dependencies"? The typical solution would be to use the Maven Shade plugin (or Gradle Shadow plugin) to copy the classes from the not-in-Maven-Central dependency into your jar. Does that sound like what you'd like to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`deploy-file` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) of the Maven Deploy Plugin to deploy the foreign JAR to Maven Central, too. See also the [Usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html#The_deploy:deploy-file_Mojo):

```sh
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
  -Durl=<Maven Central URL> \
  -DrepositoryId=<Server Id to map on the <id> under <server> section of settings.xml> \
  -Dfile=...local.../jsonic-1.2.0.jar \
  -DgroupId=com.wordpress.shuyo \
  -DartifactId=jsonic \
  -Dversion=1.2.0 \
  -DgeneratePom=true \
  -DgeneratePom.description="shuyo/language-detection"
```

Comment: You shouldn't deploy an artifact you don't own

Comment: @Michael Whether you deploy it inside your own jar or as a separate jar: In both cases you need to check the license requirements first.